# Is "agnostic" an appropriate substitute for "indifferent"?

Tags: adjectives

Recently, a co-worker used the term *agnostic* to indicate that he had no strong preference for either of the two options under consideration. I don't remember exactly what the discussion was about, but his statement was essentially:

"I am agnostic as to whether we go with A or option B."

I would use the term *indifferent* or, less formally, *I don't care.* Is this an appropriate use for *agnostic*?

Comment: indifference and "I don't care" have a bit more of an implication that the subject itself isn't important than being agnostic.

Comment: As others have noted, _agnostic_ inescapably bears some theological freight owing to its use in describing a possible view of God and religion; but any notion that _agnostic_ strictly serves as some sort of watered-down synonym for _atheistic_ is not supported historically or in current usage.

Comment: This is most certainly a malapropism. "Indifferent" is what he wanted to say. You can only be "agnostic" as to a perspective or view or position or belief. Making a choice between A or B may be motivated by a belief or perspective (e.g. a preference for one over the other), but the choice itself is not a perspective or a view, it's merely an action.

Comment: I can recall about 10 years ago being at a bicycling event and standing next to "floor pump" (tall bike tire pump) that was there for anyone to use. Someone came up and asked me if it was Schrader or Presta (valve style). "It's agnostic." I replied. They understood perfectly what I said -- the pump would automatically adapt for either type of valve. I have encountered this same terminology in other areas of technology where some device or computer program "didn't care" which style of thing it interacted with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED lists its principal meaning as the religious one:

*A person who believes that nothing is known or can be known of immaterial things, especially of the existence or nature of God. Distinguished from atheist n.*

The meaning that your colleague is adopting is described by the OED as an 'extended use' of the term. See below.

*In extended use: a person who is not persuaded by or committed to a particular point of view; a sceptic. Also: person of indeterminate ideology or conviction; an equivocator.*

So they were not using it wrongly, but in an alternate form to the main meaning.

Answer (score 4):

It sounded very strange to me, but the online Merriam-Webster gives this as one of its definitions for agnostic:   *a person who is unwilling to commit to an opinion about something* , and it also lists the word as an adjective. So,  "I am agnostic as to whether we go with A or option B" appears to be acceptable.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't sound "strange" to me. Just a bit figurative and/or informal. I can't avoid being at least slightly aware of the religious connotations, but I certainly wouldn't assume any such allusion was necessarily *intended* (in the average UK office meeting context, say). Whatever - it's more *undecided* than *don't care* to me.

Comment: I think it connotes more "I have decided to not care" ...or either alternative is equally desirable to him.

Answer (score 4):

**Agnostic** (in non-religious usage) properly means that one has not or cannot come to an opinion on a matter. There are many reasons for that, and indifference is only one of them. Another would be an insufficiency of evidence, or a contractual prohibition of favouritism.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the fellow in question is thinking of the term as it has been used in the software industry (unfortunately, IMHO) for several years. Example: "The new app is platform-agnostic." This means that the app will run regardless if you are (for example) a Mac or PC user, or a Windows 8 or WindowsXP user.

Comment: I've used "agnostic" to mean "indifferent" in conversation before, and I wasn't totally sure how it became part of my vocabulary. I'm a programmer, so "platform-agnostic" makes perfect sense for why I use it in that context.

Answer (score 0):

No sir! The word *gnostic* is the root of *agnostic*, and that has all to do with religion--not to do with indifference. Occasionally (rarely), the word *agnostic* is used to describe a non-committal attitude, but it *really* doesn't fit in your example sentence. To see why you need to look up the definition of *gnostic*. From Merriam-Webster:

`the thought and practice especially of various cults of late pre-Christian and early Christian centuries distinguished by the conviction that matter is evil and that emancipation comes through gnosis [esoteric knowledge of spiritual truth held by the ancient Gnostics to be essential to salvation]`

Now, remember that the prefix "a-" means "without". If you stretch this definition a bit, you can probably understand what a statement like, "He abstained from voting because he felt agnostic on the subject of the candidates' proposed policy changes." In this case, "agnostic" doesn't mean that the speaker doesn't care. It means that the speaker feels a distinct lack of conviction. In other words, that he or she isn't confident in either choice, and the speaker is using the word "agnostic" to explain that the reason he or she isn't voting *at all* is precisely *because* he or she isn't on board with either option. Your friend might have said, "I will not make a choice because I am agnostic on the matter," but it would be ridiculous for an every day kind of thing because the choice between A and B is probably not consequential enough in the first place that it would require any kind of conviction or certainty.

You're looking for the word *apathy*, but it doesn't quite fit in the example sentence. *Apathy* describes a complete lack of concern. You can feel apathetic on a particular topic, such as religion or the question of how Obama is doing as the President, but *apathy* isn't the best choice for a simple question because the word *apathy* is used when the topic being discussed is something about which you seemingly *should* care.

Comment: Of the 29 COCA citations for *agnostic about*, only one is about religion (two if you count a belief in fairies as 'religion').

Comment: I was in the process of elaborating as you wrote your comment.

Comment: @R Mac. I've read your edited post. Your view on the ridiculousness of being agnostic about every ay things is not shared by quite a few writers whose words are cited on the BNC, COCA and GWBE.

Comment: @Tunny can you share some such examples?

Comment: just because agnostic is loaded because of its use to categorize a type of belief in the Christian God doesn't subsume the other meanings. Its Greek for "no thought"..and can apply to any subject.

Comment: Since _gnosis_ in ancient Greek meant knowledge, the alpha-privative form _agnosis_ meant without knowledge—or in modern usage, not claiming to have knowledge or insight into a particular subject. It's easy to see how such a term would get conscripted into discourse on religion, where knowledge shades into belief (or vice versa), but there is no requirement that it be applied solely to that topic.

Answer (score 0):

**Agnostic**

someone who is doubtful or noncommittal about something eg:

```
Though I am agnostic on what terms to use, ...
```

Comment: more noncommital than doubtful.  Most often the agnostic is set on not committing to a side.

Answer (score 0):

Using agnostic as a response is a clever way to express non-commital indifference. The religious undertone gives it power on non-religious subjects in my view. I noticed this usage on a news show and was impressed with the way it got my attention.